# AngularJS : How to get a sub-total from my directive using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a situation where I'm using an ng-repeat to display a directive, and this directive is responsible for calculating a sub-total and using 2-way binding to add that sub-total to my total.

However, by using the ng-repeat, it's adding to the scope of the ng-repeat instead of my controller.  How can I get this to work correctly?

Edit:  I figured out a solution, but not sure if it's the best way to do it...

I changed:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in myArray'>
  <add-it-up sub-total='total1'></add-it-up>
</div>
```

to

```
<div ng-repeat='item in myArray'>
  <add-it-up sub-total='$parent.total1'></add-it-up>
</div>
```

and it's working.  Is there a better way to do this?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lqh0z93yc5Q5E2gNBdtG?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='testApp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <!-- This doesn't work -->
    <div ng-repeat='item in myArray'>
      <add-it-up sub-total='total1'></add-it-up>
    </div>
    {{total1}}
    <br />

    <!-- This does work -->
    <add-it-up sub-total='total2'></add-it-up>
    <add-it-up sub-total='total2'></add-it-up>
    <add-it-up sub-total='total2'></add-it-up>
    {{total2}}

    <script>
      var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

      app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myArray = [0, 1, 2];
        $scope.total1 = 0;
        $scope.total2 = 0;        
      }])

      app.directive("addItUp", function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            subTotal: "="
          },
          controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function() {
              console.log($scope.subTotal)
              $scope.subTotal += 5;
              console.log($scope.subTotal)
            })
          }]
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an object to your `$scope` containing the `total1`. Otherwise this property gets overwritten by the `ng-repeat sub-scopes`:

```
$scope.totals = {
  total1: 0,
  total2: 0       
};
```

Have a look at [this updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xPEN4HOmx3HOv05akhIB?p=preview). For more information visit [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: Great link!  Beautifully explained!  Makes much more sense now.